# Adding CSS class based on URL string through JQuery

Tags: jquery, url

I have some JQuery written which is intended so when a user navigates to 'page/2/' in Wordpress, an image appears in the sidebar.  It's CSS is set to `display:none;` initially, then I have JQuery change it to `display:block;` if that URL string is present.  The code I wrote has it backwards... so it does this to every page BUT '/page/2/'.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var url = window.location.pathname;
if(url.indexOf('/page/2/')){
    $('.sidebarimage').css("display","block");
}});
```

I always thought if there was no condition set in an If statement, it treats it as true, and anything else as false.  Should I put a `= 1` or something here?  What am I missing?

Many thanks SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if` block will be entered if the value of the condition is convertible to `true`.  In Javascript any non-zero number is `true` and the return value of `indexOf` when the string is not found is -1.  Hence any time it's not there it gives back -1 which is seen as true and the `if` block is entered.

Change the conditional to be explicit to what you're looking for

```
if (url.indexOf('/page/2/') !== -1) {
  $('.sidebarimage').css("display","block");
}
```

Comment: So before, when it DID find the `/page/2/` string, it returned a 0 (false) instead of a 1? That was only time the `true` statement didn't actually carry through.  Wouldn't it carry through for all tests then?

Comment: @RCNeil, It would carry through for every case except where the string began with `"/page/2/"`

Comment: So what # does that if-statement (my original) return when it does contain "/page/2/"?  That's what I'm asking.  I would think it would be 1, a non-zero #, and in turn, would have the TRUE statement carry through.  It was not working when it contained "/page/2/" which makes me wonder what `indexOf` returns when it finds something....

Comment: @RCNeil it would return the index in the string where `'/page/2/'` begins.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhh, that clearly shows how little I know about some of the functions I'm using in JQuery.  My head is still in PHP.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

This Jquery Code will work only for home page

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var x = location.href;
    var y = location.hostname;
    var z = 'http://' + y + '/';

        if(x == z ){
        $('.class').css("display","block");
    }
        else{
        $('.class').css("display","none");
        }
    });
```